# Joomla Category Rename Problem

Tags: category

We have a Joomla website, and I renamed a category (it was named "Active Clinical Trials" - and I changed that to just "Clinical Trials")
But - if you go to this link (open in a new tab please to remain on this post)

http://www.curefa.org/active-clinical-trials/44-clinical-trials-active-enrolling

You will see that the old Category name is still being displayed in the SEF URL, in the "breadcrumbs", and in the header of the page.
I have looked at the menu items - the categories - and have not yet discovered where the page is getting the old category name from?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks...

Comment: are you using any 3rd party plugins for SEF?

Comment: No 3rd party SEF
Just using System SEF

Comment: Do you have any plugins like Direct Alias Pro, canonical links, etc? Sorry if these questions seem basic.  I just know that personally it's the little things that get me sometimes.

Comment: I am seeing Direct Alias (disabled) and Direct Alias Pro (enabled) 
Direct Alias Pro seems to have only three options: Remove Content ID - Remove Content Category ID - and Remove Tag ID ?

Comment: Are you using a RocketTheme or Gantry 5 template?  Direct Alias has issues with those.

Comment: No - using T3 Blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sitemap it looks like there is a menu item Mobile Menu->RideAtaxia Blog ->Active Clinical Trials: http://www.curefa.org/site-map . Double check that menu alias.

Comment: You Solved It!
I had looked at "Menus" and "Menu Items" - Did not realize there was an an entry for that under "Ride Ataxia Blog"
Thank you YellowWebMonkey!
I appreciate the time you spent to help!

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the cache. Go to administrator > system > clear cache , also be sure to clear your browsers cache.

Comment: Cleared all cache (Joomla db and browser)
Problem still exists

Answer (score 2):

Have you updated the alias as well as the name of the category?  It's the alias that should be generating the URL.

The alias will automatically generate a value based on your name if left blank, but will not automatically update when you change the name.

Comment: Yes - alias was manually changed when Title was changed.
Then - when I saw the problem - I removed the alias to allow it to auto-generate from title.
Title is: Clinical Trials  Alias is: clinical-trials

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the Rebuild button in category toolbar. Some time ago I had a similar issue, and that solved it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Did try that - (prior and again just now) - did not fix the issue.

Comment: You could try the same in the menu link